# How do I export the result of a foreach function?

Tags: node.js, parsing, foreach

I used the following code for html parsing.
Of the parsed results, I want to use the 'title' and 'link' outside the code, but an error appears.

I expect the output 'title+link', but the actual output is

> console.log(title + link); ReferenceError  : title is not defined

How can I export it and use it?

```
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser();
var url = 'url address'

 parser.parseURL(url, function(err, feed) {
  console.log(feed.title);

  feed.items.forEach(function(item) {

    title = item.title;
    link = item.link;
    console.log(title + link);

  });
 });
   console.log(title + link);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, why that `console.log(title + link)` appears twice, why it appears outside of the callback function's scope or why you even expect a `console.log` statement to export anything. I suggest that you start with what it is that you want to do, because it seems that all the other questions marks derive from that.

Comment: @goodvibration  
I want approach html and parsing 'title' and 'link'. Then export this result to json responsebody. like :
 version: "2.0",
    template: {
      outputs: [
        {
          simpleText: {
            text: title + link
          }
        }
      ]
    }
So I need running the last line. 
2 console.log just check out the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser();
var url = 'url address'

 parser.parseURL(url, function(err, feed) {
  const list = [];

  feed.items.forEach(function(item) {
    const title = item.title;
    const link = item.link;
    list.push(title + link);
  });

  console.log(list);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do below code.Use async.foreach instead of forEach.

```
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser();
var url = 'url address'

parser.parseURL(url, function(err, feed) {
console.log(feed.title);

async.forEach(feed.items(item), function (err, callback){ 
title = item.title;
link = item.link;
console.log(title + link);
}, function(err) {
console.log('iterating done');
});
});
console.log(title + link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call **JSON.parse()** before accessing your feed properties

```
var obj = JSON.parse(feed);
var title= obj.title;
```